# Ansible setup module's filter is not working when use with playbook

Tags: ansible

I am trying to `filter` `setup` module for a specific `fact`, but no output when doing so with a `playbook`. It works well with `adhoc command`!

example playbook:

```
---
- name: facts test
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
  - ansible.builtin.setup:
      filter:
        - "ansible_all_ipv4_addresses"

  - debug: var=ansible_all_ipv4_addresses
...
```

Output:

```
TASK [debug var=ansible_all_ipv4_addresses] ****************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "ansible_all_ipv4_addresses": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!"
}
```

Expected Output:

```
TASK [debug var=ansible_all_ipv4_addresses] ****************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "ansible_all_ipv4_addresses": [
        "192.168.1.1"
    ]
}
```

Adhoc command `ansible localhost -m setup -a "filter=ansible_all_ipv4_addresses"` produces proper  output.
Any idea what is wrong here?
Ansible Version I've tested:

```
$ ansible --version
ansible 2.9.6
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is almost certainly a problem with your ansible version. The `filter` parameter takes a `list` since `ansible-core` version `2.11`, you are probably using an older one.

You have two possibilities:

- Change the filter to `filter: "ansible_all_ipv4_addresses"`
- Update to the latest version of ansible

Comment: Yes, I've tested up to 2.10 but not > 2.10. Thank you for pointing this out.